# I get "access is denied" when I try to print a page using jquery.PrintElement.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

Ok so the usage scenario is as follows:

I have a button that opens the current page for printing using the jquery print plugin.

```
 $("#Section1").printElement({
        leaveOpen: true,
        printMode: 'popup',
        pageTitle: '<%=Resources.Reporting.Text_Title%>'
    });
```

The result is what I expect. A print preview window and a printing settings dialog are shown.

If I click one more time and the print preview page is minimised i get "Access Is Denied" js error pointing to JQuery.printElement.js.

If it's not minimised it just opens the same print preview popup as before.

This is IE behaviour just to mention. In Firefox there's a "Not Available" alert from the browser.

Is this something I can fix?

From what I've searched so far this "Access is denied error" is linked to 
making a call to a sub domain from a different domain"

Comment: What is JQuery.printElement.js?

Comment: Is there anything unusual about the element you are trying to print, like it being in an iframe? Or is it just a normal div? There seems to be a lot of people finding little bugs with this library. I would suggest going [here](https://github.com/erikzaadi/jQueryPlugins/issues?labels=printElement) and opening up an issue if you have no luck here.

Comment: Try to upgrade printElement to a [newer version](https://github.com/Akkuma/jQueryPlugins/blob/master/jQuery.printElement/jquery.printElement.js).  Also, I suggest using `printMode: iframe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx Blowsie, it might give that a go.

The problem was due to the fact that the print plugin tried to open a new window with the
same name every time I would press the print page button. I changed it so that a new and unique name is used every time the print preview page is open.

```
  if (opts["printMode"].toLowerCase() == 'popup') {
        popupOrIframe = window.open('about:blank', 'printElementWindow', 'width=650,height=440,scrollbars=yes');
        documentToWriteTo = popupOrIframe.document;
    }
```

to:

```
    var windowName = "printElementWindow";
    windowName = windowName + (Math.round(Math.random() * 99999)).toString();
    if (opts["printMode"].toLowerCase() == 'popup') {
        popupOrIframe = window.open('about:blank', windowName, 'width=650,height=440,scrollbars=yes');
        documentToWriteTo = popupOrIframe.document;
    }
```